# Query within multiple csv files for get the suitable data-set based on given conditions on pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy

I have approximately 25 csv datasets. Where every csv file has many common column names. Now these all csv file are for speech recognition domain where you can work on text to speech projects. Choosing a dataset for specific kind of project needs to see all 25 datasets and choose the preferred one.

Such as, for project `A` I need specific dataset which has specific features in it. Like, column `Speacker` is `Male`, `Sampling rate` is `48000`, `Language` is `en` etc etc.

How to read all those cvs files and get the name of the data set which matches the conditions.

I tried to use `itertuples` over the rows of csv to find the row which contains the targeted information. However, I need just the name of data as a outcome.

I didn't find much to look for here:

```py
import os, fnmatch

result = []

def find(pattern, path):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for name in files:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, pattern):
                result.append(os.path.join(root, name))
    return result


csv = find('*.csv', './')
```

This function return all those 25 csv file and now I am stuck to write logic to search over all the csv file and find the name of the dataset where column contain given values. I am looking for something where my code accepts multiple arguments (Conditions) and query those 25 csv files columns and find the match in every column. Then tell the name of the dataset which contains such features.

Conditions:

```
Language = 'en'
Gender = 'Male'
Sample rate = 48000
```

Expected outout:

```
Following Data has such features:
1) Data_xyz
2) Data_abc
```

#### Edited

Comment: Do these values have to be on the same row?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. No they don't have to be in same row. Please let me make it clear again, There are `same named columns` in all 25 data-sets but values can be different inside the columns and I want to get the name of dataset where `given column names` and `their respective values` match.

Comment: In your example datasets, both are True right? Since they both contain `Male` and `En` somwhere in the dataframe.

Comment: Not actually. Since I have provided two search conditions. One for column `Gender` and one for `Lang` so only the data where these two columns have these values should be found. So data_1 is the answer here. As data_2 has `Gender` column as `Female`. Thanks again ..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over each row, and if all of the key words in your query are somewhere in that row, you have a match.  You can use a list comprehension where you check 'if all items in the query are in the row i'm looking at, consider it a match'.  In this approach we're actually capturing those rows, into a new dataframe and looking at the shape of the resulting dataframe. Shape is a tuple (rows, cols) so if we look at shape[0] of the resulting dataframe it will either be zero if there are no matches, or 1+ if there are rows that match.

```
data_0 = {'Name':['Ned', 'Ped', 'Ded'], 'Gender': ['Male', 'Male', 'Female'], 'Lang': ['En', 'De', 'Fr']}
data_1 = {'Name':['Sia', 'Kori', 'Maya'], 'Gender': ['Female', 'Female','Female' ], 'Lang': ['En', 'En','En']}
>>> for c, data_frame in enumerate(final_data):
...     if data_frame[data_frame.apply(lambda row: all([i in row.values for i in query]), axis=1)].shape[0] >= 1:
...             print('match on data_{}'.format(c))
...
match on data_0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. However, if I am not wrong this takes `Male` and `Female` interchangeably.  So I don't get right data-set back. Also, is there any way that this script can ignore cases of the entries and work for both uppercase and lower case entries. Like, `male`== `Male` and so on. Thanks

Comment: I believe you may not understand what the code is doing.  Try changing the data and seeing if it still returns what you want.  It should.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works fine. I would be more interested to learn in detail what this code is doing. Although, you did wrote details but can you explain a bit more. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `Series.isin` to check if the column has one of the values in `query`. Then we save the index of the dataframe into a list, since we cannot save the name of the dataframe in a list:

```
mathces= [x for x, df in enumerate(final_data) if (df['Gender'].isin(query) & df['Lang'].isin(query)).any()]
```

**Ouput**

```
print(matches)
[0]
```

This means that only the first dataframe has a match.